# Using Hyper On Windows for cmd and Git

Tags: windows, windows-10, ubuntu, command-line, git

I just installed Oh My Zsh (Hyper) by following the instructions on [How to Install Oh My Zsh! on Windows 10 Home Edition](https://dev.to/vsalbuq/how-to-install-oh-my-zsh-on-windows-10-home-edition-49g2#the-benefits). I use it on Windows 10, but there are some issues that does not let me use it properly:

Here is my settings file of Hyper:

```
// shell: 'C:\\Users\\<username>\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\WindowsApps\\ubuntu2004.exe', //for cmd
shell: 'C:\\Program Files\\Git\\git-cmd.exe', //for Git

// shellArgs: [], //for cmd
shellArgs: ['--command=usr/bin/bash.exe', '-l', '-i'], //for Git
```

**1.** I am wondering is it possible to use different terminal on different tabs as I can use in cmder?

**2.** Is there any feature to save last opened tabs after closing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you need Hyper for a specific reason, I recommend [Windows Terminal](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal).
I use it with Oh My Zsh in Ubuntu WSL2.

I use the font Caskaydia Cove from [Nerd Fonts](https://www.nerdfonts.com/font-downloads).

I use the [agnoster theme](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/wiki/Themes#agnoster) but there are many others available.

For using different terminals in different tabs, it is a built-in Windows Terminal feature, but for Hyper you can try [this](https://hyper.is/store/hyper-launch-menu).

For saving and loading last opened tabs, it looks like both [Hyper](https://github.com/vercel/hyper/pull/945) and [Windows Terminal](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/766) are working on the feature, but neither are ready yet.

Comment: Thanks, I tried Windows Terminal and yes the new version is really great. Actually the reason that I want to use Hyper is to get a great theme as shown on [this](https://res.cloudinary.com/practicaldev/image/fetch/s--sgyw_MrX--/c_limit%2Cf_auto%2Cfl_progressive%2Cq_auto%2Cw_880/https://i.imgur.com/Xck61P4.png) link. If it is possible to get the same look, then of course I would prefer to use Windows Terminal. Is it possible? And how?

Comment: By the way, Nerd Fonts seems good, but I did not see Caskaydia Code.

Comment: its the 4th font down on the right

Comment: what is that theme called? you might find something similar [here](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/wiki/Themes)

Comment: Perfect explanations, many thanks. On the other hand, I think I can reach the same result by using Windows Terminal instead of Hyper. So, could you please suggest a proper example about installation Oh My Zsh and Windows Terminal on Windows 10? There are many useless article and now I am looking https://www.jondjones.com/tactics/productivity/how-to-become-a-windows-terminal-god-with-wsl2-zsh-and-oh-my-zsh/

Comment: On that page, when I run `code ~/zshrc` on the related step, the zshrc file is opened as empty file on VS Code. I re-tryed again after resetting Ubuntu, but does not make any sense.

Comment: Amigo? Any idea for my last comments?

Comment: you need to open `code ~/.zshrc`, note the `.`

Comment: Yes, I see but does not make any sense and opened file is still empty.

Comment: thats weird. there should be a default there. the default you can get from [here](https://github.com/ohmyzsh/ohmyzsh/blob/master/templates/zshrc.zsh-template)